# What happens to an inverse limit if one arrow is changed?

Tags: category-theory

In [Wikipedia's definition of the inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)#Limits), the following diagram if the universal cone appears:

[image: universal cone]

I know that by dualizing, i.e. essentially flipping **all** the arrows, $L$ becomes the co-limit, i.e. the universal co-cone.

But what kind of universal object $L$ would be defined by flipping **just the dashed arrow** of the map $u$ in above diagram? Would it still turn $L$ into the co-limit, even though the arrows of $\phi_X,\phi_Y,\psi_X,\psi_Y$ have not changed?

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray As an easy exercise, let's do this in $\mathrm{Set}$ for _all_ non-empty diagrams: There's always a cone with cone point $\emptyset$, the initial object in $\mathrm{Set}$, so whatever $L$ is it must admit a map to the empty set. Of course, this directly implies that $L = \emptyset$, so in this category the notion collapses, and not exactly to the colimit. I kindly suggest actually working with the notion on your own for a while and then updating the question with your results.